# Finde correct name for EF context

Tags: c, entity-framework

I've added a entity framework model from a database using the wizard called EnterpriseDownloadRepository.edmx

I can't access it when trying to set up the context in the same project.

var context = new FileDownloadEntites()

"FileDownloadEntites"  is not recognized by visual studio 2012

Comment: If you put your cursor on `FileDownloadEntities` and press `CTRL + .`, does it pop up anything saying `using ...`?  Also, did you mean to use the `c#` tag?

Comment: If your references are right, you can open the designer and see what your context is actually named.. It could be something like FileDownloadEntites1 in the generated code

Comment: where in the designer does it have the context name?

Comment: found it in properties of the designer window.  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it in properties of the designer window.

right click in a blank area of the designer window, select properties, and it is in a property called "Entity container Name"